# Spring mapping effected by @ResponseBody

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am making an ajax call to my Spring controller to get data from a blob object. I convert the blob to String, and try to return it. If I don't use @ResponseBody annotation, I get a 404 error, but using the annotation solves this.I tried specifying different datatypes in the ajax code, but it has no effect.
Can somebody please explain this behaviour to me. Also any suggestions regarding passing blob data back, in a better way ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/BlobData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String genBlobData(int Id) throws SQLException {


        Blob blob =  daoImpl.getBlob(Id);
        byte[] content = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
        String temp = new String(content);
        return temp;
    }
```

And the ajax :

```
  $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "text",
                        url: 'BlobData',
                        data: {Id:Id},               
                        success: function(data) 
                                {
                                     var newWindow = window.open();newWindow.document.write(data); 
                                     /* alert(data); */
                                 }
                        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `@ResponseBody`, the returned string is expected to be a relative path to your view (e.g. JSP file), hence the 404.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-resolver.

Comment: But the function genBlobData should be called even if view is not resolved, why do I get a 404 for '/BlobData',

Comment: @SKaul I believe the method does get called (put a beakpoint or a sysout to check it). Just when resolving the view, since not found, a 404 is returned.

Comment: You are right, the method is getting called ! Thanks, any views on passing blobs as string ?